# Is it possible to print backspace characters while generating downloadable CSV in PHP?

Tags: php, csv, header, backspace

Is it possible to echo backspace while generating output in PHP?

Situation:

```
if ($this->s) {
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=exportevent.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    echo $this->s;
    exit;
}
```

I wrote the above code in one of my views (Zend MVC), while printing $s, a number of (30) blank rows are appended.  I would like to backspace those rows. Is there any method for that?

Comment: Shouldn't you rather be removing those lines *before* outputting them?

Comment: actually $s doesn't containce any unwanted charecters , form somewhere else these blank rows are appending tried to find where it was but not found , so thinking that can we able to do back space so that the line brekes can be avoided. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have to remove leading blank rows at the point of echo, then

```
echo ltrim($this->s);
```

to remove leading spaces, line feeds and carriage returns before the echo.

But you really should be preventing those lines from being generated in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

you may use

```
  if(!empty($row)) {
  print $row;
  }
```